# Add image in pdf using itext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, pdf-generation, itext

I'am creating Spring MVC web application.My image is in folder webapp/resources/img/logo.png of my MVC application.How to load image from that folder to pdf.

I tried with this code.But its trowing java.io.FileNotFoundException.

```
  String imageUrl = "webapp/resources/img/logo.png"

  logo = Image.getInstance(imageUrl);
```

Answer (score 6):

Enhanced you find a example how I does it:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\test.pdf"));
document.open();

Image img = Image.getInstance(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("attention-icon.jpg"));
img.scaleAbsolute(10, 10);

Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.add(new Chunk(img, 0,0));

document.add(new Paragraph(phrase));
document.close();
```

I think I your case the file "webapp/resources/img/logo.png" is to relativ. Try to create a File Object to check its location:

```
File logo = new File("webapp/resources/img/logo.png");
if(! logo.exists()){
    LOG.warn("File " + logo.getName() + " not exists");
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me.In your example,where did you store the image "attention-icon.jpg" ?

Comment: It *is* the correct answer though. You can place the icon on different locations: in the working directory of the web app, in your jar,... This question is unrelated to iText. It's merely a matter of knowing how to access resources from a web application.

Comment: In my case the attention-icon.jpg is part of the classpath. Like Bruno said the matter is to locate resources in a web application scope from your application classpath. I'm sure spring delivers that kind of feature.

Comment: Just a side thought. The OP mentioned that the image is in the webapp folder (and not under WEB-INF). resources folder in the webapp folder is not a real resources folder. Would be a good idea to place it under src/main/resources and then load it using a relative path from the resources folder. Then it will be on the classpath and the server will have no problem finding it.